# Scrapy not working

Tags: scrapy

Just a question from newbie about scrapy...

the code below is not working...

```
    import scrapy

class stackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'stack'
start_urls = [
    'http://stackoverflow.com'
]
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
item = StackItem()


def parse(self, response):
    self.crawlGeneral(response)

def crawlGeneral(self, response):       
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="question-mini-list"]'):
        self.item['name'] = sel.xpath('div/div[2]/h3/a').extract()
    yield self.item
```

However, everything is working fine if i don't make a function...

```
class stackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'stack'
start_urls = [
    'http://stackoverflow.com'
]
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
item = StackItem()


def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[@id="question-mini-list"]'):
        self.item['name'] = sel.xpath('div/div[2]/h3/a').extract()
    yield self.item
    self.crawlGeneral(response)

def crawlGeneral(self, response):
    print 'Now i am in!... '
```

Anyone can figure out what's wrong with the upper code?
Just trying to make it nicer by separating them into functions...

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return.

```
def parse(self, response):
    return self.crawlGeneral(response)
```